# How to Fetch value from another table and INSERT the same data to specific row in a different table

Tags: php, sql

I am seeking help on how to use data fetched from a different table and INSERT the same data to a DIFFERENT table while specifying the row which data will be stored considering the session created.

```
if (isset($_GET['apply'])) {

    $sess_id = $_SESSION['t_user_id'];
if (isset($_SESSION['UserName']) && $_SESSION['UserName'] == true) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts))
    {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(commission)
    SELECT cost 
    FROM `tbl_jobs` 
    WHERE ID = '$sess_id' ";

    $update_user_role = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$update_user_role) {

    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection,$query));
    }
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
}
```

[image: tables]

Currently its fetching the data from different table and posting to unintended row as per session.

I will like to see the data fetched from the different table being posted to row which is equal to username session created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `update`:

```
update users u join
       tbl_jobs j
       on u.id = j.user_id  -- guessing at the `JOIN` condition here
    set commission = j
    where u.id = ?;
```

Also note the use of `?`.  This is a parameter placeholder -- and an indication that you should be using parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: its not working. note that in tbl_jobs table primary id is enc_id and in users table primary id is ID

Comment: @DominicTanui . . . You need some way to connect them.  Or if there is only one row, use a `cross join` instead of `join`.

Comment: ```$query = "UPDATE u
 SET u.commission = 1

  FROM users u
  INNER JOIN tbl_jobs j
  ON u.ID =j.ID
  
  WHERE j.commission = 1";``` is that correct?